# Insert page break before each element in list

Tags: microsoft-word, list

I have a Word document with 400 questions which are in a numbered list. How do I create a macro to insert a page break before each element in the list?
For example here I want a page break before 5

[image: Example questions]

Answer (score 1):

You can get this done easily by creating a new style of modifying an existing style. You need to follow the following steps to get that.

1. **Right-Click Modify** an existing/new style.
2. Go to **Format > Numbering**
3. Choose the desired **numbering format**
4. Go to **Format > Paragraph**
5. Make sure to check the "**Page break before**" check box
   in the **Lines and Page breaks** tab.
6. Make sure to choose the
   **Normal** style in the "**Style for following paragraph**" drop-down.

Please see screenshot below for the above mentioned steps: 
[image: Bullets and Page-breaks]

Comment: Thank you. But it insert page break before each line, not just the numbered list elements. Is there a vba subroutine that I could use to select only the numbered list elements and then change their style type?

Comment: You don't need VBA for this. I've tested this out and its working properly. You need to **make sure** you've chosen the 5th & 6th option properly. In the image I provided, you can see the output.

Comment: Thing is 5 and 6 is just an example. I have ~4000 such questions. It will be impossible to manually select them all and apply this. In the document, the style is same for all text.

Comment: I have solved it by using Find and Replace. Matched the formatting in Find and replaced it with your solution (Page break before)